# SQL help in resultant table

Tags: sql, select

I am doing my Bsc IT major project and i am doing Cinema Ticketing System
i have 3 tables

movies

```
   movieID   movieName  ticketPrice
    1001       3 idiots     200
    1002       ready    300
    1003       robot    250
```

schedule

```
showId   movieId
9001     1001
9002     1003
9003     1002
```

tickets

```
ticketNo  showId   soldBy  
21        9001     A
73        9001     B
23        9001     A
22        9001     A
64        9002     A
34        9003     B
11        9001     A
98        9001     A
38        9003     B
78        9001     B
24        9002     A
31        9001     A
```

i want to get the following result

```
userName  showId  TotalAmount(Product of Count(TicketNo) and ticketPrice)
A         9001    1200
A         9002    500
B         9001    400
B         9003    600
```

pls help me

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  t.soldBy AS userName,
  t.showId,
  SUM(m.ticktPrice) AS TotalAmount
FROM
  tickets t
  INNER JOIN schedule s ON s.showId = t.showId
  INNER JOIN movies m ON m.movieId = s.movieId
GROUP BY
  t.soldBy,
  t.showId
```

Comment: `SUM(t.ticketNo * m.ticktPrice)` should be just `SUM(m.ticktPrice)`, `t.ticketNo` is just a ticket identifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.soldBy userName, t.showId showId, count(t.ticketNo) * m.tickeprice total
from tickets t
inner join schedule s on t.showId = s.showId
inner join movies m on m.movieId = s.movieId
group by t.soldBy, t.showId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  T.`soldBy`,
  T.`showId`,
  SUM(M.`ticketPrice`) 
FROM
  tickets AS T 
  INNER JOIN schedule AS S 
    ON T.`showId` = S.`showId` 
  INNER JOIN movies AS M 
    ON S.`movieID` = M.`movieID` 
GROUP BY T.`soldBy`,
  T.`showId` ;
```

Just a thought: In many places it is customary to have different prices in a cinema not only because of the movie, but because of the time the movie is playing (i.e. mornings are cheaper, weekend evenings are more expensive). If you want to take this into consideration, then you shouldn't link the price to a movie, but to a show.

Comment: it doesnt work.....................any way thanks for suggestion earlier i had same thinking but later i change my mind and include price in movies table

Comment: sorry thanks it works perfectly, i type ad  SUM(S.`ticketPrice`) thats why it wasnt working now it work perfectly